# In a Sharepoint List: Display an Image (field type "Hyperlink or Picture")

Tags: list, hyperlink, image-display, json-formatting

I have a Sharepoint list that has a column filled with URLs (which point to images stored elsewhere on the Sharepoint site).

The column settings and JSON are shown in the below image:
[image: Column Settings and JSON for column formatting]

When I fill in the field for the list items, the URL creates itself as a hyperlink - with the "Enter a url" AND "Enter display text" fields BOTH populated with the link:
[image]

If I delete the text out of the "Enter display text" field, the picture displays as expected in the list. Is there a way that I can modify the JSON to remove the need to delete the URL text? I have hundres of items in the list, so doing this deleting for all fields would not be realistic.

Thank you

Here is my JSON

```
{
"elmType": "img",
"txtContent": "",
"style": {
    "width": "100px"
},
"attributes": {
    "src": {
        "operator": "+",
        "operands": [
            "@currentField",
            "@currentField.desc"
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the use of this json code? What are you doing using this json?

Comment: I am using it for column formatting within the Sharepoint list. Is this an inelegant method for formatting columns?

Comment: No, It is the right way to use json for column formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it. Set `src` attribute directly. `src` is just URL to an image, so why to use description at all. If you look at the rendered HTML code using Developer dashboard (F12) you will find that the `src` of `img` tag contains url and description.

[image]

Simply use:

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
      "width": "100px"
  },
  "attributes": {
      "src": "@currentField"
  }
}
```

If you want clickable image use this:

```
{
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
      "href": "@currentField",
      "target": "_blank"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "width": "100px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "@currentField"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I recommend to use `$schema` and some intelligent IDE e.g. **Visual Studio Code**. Using it will give you hints what you can use.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField"
}
```

> Reference:
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions

Comment: Fantastic, Thank you!

Is there a way to modify this JSON so that clicking on the image takes you to the image (when viewing the list as a whole - it already does so when viewing one list item in a popout window).

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working:   
'{
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
      "width": "100px"
  },
  "attributes": {
      "src": "@currentField",
      "href": "@currentField",
      "target": "_blank"
  }
}'

Comment: `img` tag does not have `href` or `target` attributes. You are mixing image with link. So, what do you want from it? Image or link? Or link with image?

Comment: @AlasdairDuncan se modified answer.

Comment: @AlasdairDuncan sorry, I just read you previous comment :) I somehow missed it. But my modified answer will help you ;)

Comment: Brilliant - this is working perfectly. Thank you Lukas!

Comment: @AlasdairDuncan I have saved my image in SharePoint library, can I use your method to display the img I have saved there? What I am trying to achieve is every time users try to open the new list(form) they see the image on top of the list