# How to automatically load URL image link without using edit grid view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I have a SharePoint list that contains image URLs, the type is "Multiple lines of text"
They asked me to show the URL as an image and I followed the solution here:
[In a Sharepoint List: Display an Image (field type "Hyperlink or Picture")](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255389/in-a-sharepoint-list-display-an-image-field-type-hyperlink-or-picture)

I mean it worked, but only if you're inside edit grid view.
outside grid view:

[image: outside edit grid view]

with edit grid view:

[image: inside edit grid view]

I have tried changing the type, making a new column with hyperlink or image as the type, activating rich text and various JSON/advice that is available here.

(i'm just an intern, I don't really know this)

Comment: Are you using external URLs for images or you want to upload images from local computer for new list items?

Comment: I am using External URLs for images sir @GaneshSanap
(it came from an excel file, if that helps)

Comment: Can you include current JSON you are using and few examples of image URLs in your question? I will do some tests from my end and provide you working JSON

Comment: '{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "attributes": {
    "href": "@currentField",
    "target": "_blank"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "width": "500px",
        "height": "250px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "@currentField"
      }
    }
  ]
}'

Comment: sorry I couldn't reply immediately, but heres the json I am using. I just copy and pasted from [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/255389/in-a-sharepoint-list-display-an-image-field-type-hyperlink-or-picture)

I dont know if I can provide a link to the companies photos though, im sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft updated something in backend which affects external images referred in SharePoint JSON formatting.

When you refer external images in JSON formatting, **src** in img element is changed to **data-untrusted-src** automatically, like:

[image]

You can fix this issue by adding external site domain from which you are using images in **HTML Field Security** settings, detailed steps given at: [SharePoint Online: External Image URLs not working in JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/08/27/sharepoint-online-external-image-urls-not-working-in-json-formatting/)

I just tested this and it worked for me:

[image]

**Similar thread**: [Hyperlink/Picture Column suddenly breaks external images in Gallery/Card Designer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/hyperlink-picture-column-suddenly-breaks-external-images-in/m-p/3819467/highlight/false#M12515)

Comment: THIS WORKED! thank you so much sir